# How can I convert Python number to 1 byte C type?

Tags: python, c, ctypes, avr

I'm having some issues with communication between python script (on my laptop) and a C program running on a AVR microcontroller. They are communicating through UART. My issue is right now I have the following set up.

Python sending data:

```
data = port.write(struct.pack("b", val))
```

Python reading data:

```
v = struct.unpack('B', d)[0]
print "%s: %d" % ( time.ctime(time.time()), v )
```

C (AVR) reading data:

```
received = (uint8_t) UDR0;
```

C (AVR) writing data (echo):

```
UDR0 = received;
```

My issue is with this set up the numbers my python script are getting back are as follows:

send: 0 - 31, receive: 224 - 255
send: 32 - 63 receive: 32 - 63
send: 62 -95 receive: 224 - 255
send: 96 - 100 receive: 224 - 228

I don't understand why these numbers are matching up how they are but I suspect it's because of my data types. I thought about using chr() and ord() to convert to and from characters but there has to be an easier (more understandable) way. I started looking into ctypes in python and was looking to use the c_ubyte function but was unable to figure out how to use it correctly. I fairly new to python. Does anyone have any suggestions on where my logic is incorrect?

Again, my guess is the conversions and using signed vs unsigned data types.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested with a serial terminal program that communication works i.e. that your serial read/write routines are correct in the microcontroller code?

Comment: No I have not. How would this help considering the microcontroller is merely echoing back what it is receiving?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. The code is correct. I have an issue with my AVR board or my UART module. When I was sending values 0 - 31 the board was receiving 0b11100000 - 0b11111111. For 32 - 63 the board was receiving 0b00100000 - 0b00111111. For 64 - 95 the board was receiving 0b11100000 - ob11111111. For 96 - 100 the board was receiving 0b11100000 - 0b11100100.

I don't know why I'm getting these values yet. I find it very strange that the 3 most significant bits are flipping the way they are. To solve my problem for now until I figure out what's wrong (looking into if it's my UART module) I'm using a subset of 25 values and incrementing my values by 4 to get the 0 - 100 range I want.

Comment: I've checked the baud rates many times. It's an 8 bit microcontroller so I believe I can only send/receive 1 bytes at a time. Do you think it could be an issue with UART module?

Comment: Check it with an oscilloscope. The AVR USART puts 0 bits in the top bits if configured to 5 bit mode, which doesn't match your data. Do you mean the low 5 bits are the expected values? How closely together are bytes transmitted?

Comment: It's set to 8 bit mode. I 3 most significant bits are what are screwy. The 5 least significant bits are expected values. I tell it when to send so I've tested milliseconds and multiple seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a quick look at the wire form of the transmissions. There's always a start bit 0, then eight data bits with LSB first, then a stop bit 1. From the description, we're getting strange data in 3 bits, correct in 5, so there are 8 patterns to compare. I'll write the wire format right to left here.

```
>>> for i,highbits in enumerate('111 001 111 111 111'.split()):
...   print '1{:03b}ddddd0\t1{}ddddd0'.format(i,highbits)
...
1000ddddd0      1111ddddd0
1001ddddd0      1001ddddd0
1010ddddd0      1111ddddd0
1011ddddd0      1111ddddd0
1100ddddd0      1111ddddd0
```

We don't have test data for the whole set. What we see is a whole bunch of combinations where bits are set that shouldn't be, with one set of exceptions that look correct (0x20-0x3f). An analog timing issue could have explained some of the behaviour (at least bit 5 is consistently set), but it seems odd that the second pattern goes low but the fourth doesn't.

I'm short on ideas what specifically would be going on. It's too low values to be an issue of things like your file descriptor being set to UTF-8 encoding. The part where you encode as signed and decode as unsigned also doesn't matter since you use values in the range 0..127. Software issues would mostly clear high bits anyway, with format issues generally only varying a single bit for parity.

I'd really like an oscilloscope trace as well as a schematic of what's actually connected on the serial lines. Some connections (like through a capacitor or transformer) require patterns that alternate frequently enough, though even with those the shown patterns are surprising. Observing the true wire patterns would at least tell us where the distortion is happening, and with luck point at what sort of change it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just to exclude the microcontroller-side software from the "suspects" and concentrate on the communication line - connect Rx/Tx on MCU side and try to send and receive what you have just sent. Campare what you have received against what you have sent. Both sent and received buffers should match. Then we know for sure - there is something wrong with the communication line settings between the sensder and the receiver.